# How to check image is visible (Webdriver)

Tags: java, html, css, selenium

I have an image which becomes invisble after a certain width size. I'm not sure how to test this using selenium.

```
<img id="removeimg" class="col-md-5" src="images/abc-image.png" alt="abc">
```

and the following is my css.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
#removeimg  {
    display: none;
}
```

I have the following test java for this. But I'm not sure this is the right way to do it.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(System.getProperty("webDriverUrl")), DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(991, 1100));
    baseUrl = System.getProperty("baseUrl");
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
}

@Test
public void testImageNotPresent(){
    driver.findElements(By.id("removeimg");
  }
```

**UPDATE**

I've added an update to my test java.

```
@Test
public void testImageNotPresent(){
    driver.findElement(By.id("removeimg")).isDisplayed();
    assertFalse(isElementPresent(By.id("removeimg")));
}
```

But this fails when ran. I want it to pass the test if the image is not displayed on the page, but fail if it is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working.

```
@Test
public void testImageNotPresent(){
    WebElement img = driver.findElement(By.id("removeimg"));
    assertEquals("none", img.getCssValue("display"));
}
```

Comment: Don't check for the `display` style - it is not a reliable way to determine element's visibility.

Comment: @alecxe why? I'm still new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a combination of `setSize()` and `isDisplayed()`:

```
WebElement img = driver.findElement(By.id("removeimg"));

driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(991, 1100));
System.out.println(img.isDisplayed()); 

driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
System.out.println(img.isDisplayed());
```

If you are interested in how selenium webdriver determines visibility, visit this spec:

- [Element Displayedness](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#element-displayedness)

Comment: public void testImageNotPresent(){
        driver.findElement(By.id("removeimg")).isDisplayed();
    }
This is what I've changed it to. The test passes but is this a correct way? Also how can I test when the image in invisible?

Comment: @MichelleAshwini `isDisplayed()` method returns a true or a false depending on element's visibility. Assert it to be true if it should be displayed and to be false if not.

Comment: I've added a new line:
driver.findElement(By.id("removeimg")).isDisplayed();
        assertFalse(isElementPresent(By.id("removeimg")));
But this then fails when testing

Comment: @MichelleAshwini what is `isElementPresent`? You can use `assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id("removeimg")).isDisplayed())` and `assertFalse(driver.findElement(By.id("removeimg")).isDisplayed())`.